# Quick Smoke goes weirdly flat at default settings (2.93.4)

Tags: animation, particles, physics

Basically, the Quick Smoke seems to behave as if it was contained within a cube, with the smoke going flat a little over the emitter object, even though there's no cube in the scene other than the Domain itself. I haven't changed any settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use also default scene so you can be sure there is not any hidden obstacle object? Bottom part seems to be blocky thanks to low resolution, but top flat smoke looks like end of domain. Please share your file https://blend-exchange.com/ if issue persists?

Comment: Yes, I've been using the default scene. In fact, here's a Quick Smoke done using the default Cube of all things. https://blend-exchange.com/b/w8bPb4sm

Comment: which blender version are you using? It works perfectly fine to me when I opened your file

Comment: It's in the name of the question, 2.93.4

Comment: Okay, after you said that it works on your end, I figured it out. Turns out that, for SOME REASON the WiggleBone addon breaks Quick Smoke, even though it should only interact with armatures.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after MikoCG said that it works on their end, I figured it out. Turns out that, for SOME REASON the WiggleBone addon breaks Quick Smoke, even though it should only interact with armatures.